# Fetching the string inside single quote

Tags: sed, xml

```
<source file='/home/anpham/Projects/vm-builder/30G'/>
```

I tried to use sed command to extract the absolute path from the output above but the output doesn't trim the string.
The following commands is my attempt.

```
virsh dumpxml --domain "test1" | grep 'source file' | head -1 | sed '/^<source$/d'
```

The Output is still:

```
<source file='/home/anpham/Projects/vm-builder/30G'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any sed in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ sed "s/.*<source file='\([^']*\).*/\1/" file
/home/anpham/Projects/vm-builder/30G
```

Comment: I edit the answered to my need.

Answer (score 8):

To extract the value of all `file` attributes of all `source` nodes in an XML document, you may use `xmlstarlet` like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//source/@file' -nl file.xml
```

Or, reading from your `virsh` command:

```
virsh dumpxml --domain "test1" | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//source/@file' -nl
```

---

The issue with your pipeline is that the final `sed` command tries to delete all lines that consist of the exact string `<source` (and nothing else).  You don't have such lines in the input to `sed`.

Comment: Work as expected, but xmlstartlet must be installed. I still like this solution since it provides simplicity.

Comment: @vincentpham You're already using `virsh` which is another program that I'm presuming "must be installed". You could just install `xmlstarlet` together with `virsh` whenever you're doing a new installation (just like installing `jq` when you install any other utility that produces JSON output).

Comment: my current system prompt me to install xmlstarlet. Since I'm building a bash script from virsh, installing extra packages is not really preferred. In short, @Ed Morton's answer would be a safer approach to produce sufficient output.

Comment: @vincentpham It's entirely your own call, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

First: your sed command will never match anything but a line which only contents the word `source`. This is because you put `^` (begin of line) right before and `$` (end of line) right after the word `source`. 
Second: it can be done without grep and head:

```
virsh dumpxml --domain "test1" | sed -ne 's/\s*<source file=.\([^\/].*\).\/>.*/\1/; t end; b; :end; p; Q'
```

Comment: I still have some spaces at the beginning.

Comment: modified the answer to accommodate white spaces at the beginning of the line.